# Seeking Advice on High Number of PHP-FPM Processes in Magento Environment (Magento 2.4.6 & php 8.2)

Tags: magento2.4.6, php-fpm, php8.2

Seeking Advice on High Number of PHP-FPM Processes in Magento Environment (Magento 2.4.6 & php 8.2 )
Hello Magento Community,

I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently managing a Magento store and have observed a high number of PHP-FPM processes on my server, even during periods of moderate traffic. I'm seeking advice and insights from the community to better understand and optimize the PHP-FPM configuration for Magento.

Here are some specifics about my environment:

PHP-FPM Configs:

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
access.log = /var/log/php-fpm/access.log
php_value[memory_limit] = 768M
php_value[post_max_size] = 24M
php_value[upload_max_filesize] = 24

The servers are equipped with [8-cores and 16gb Memory with load balancer], and I'm noticing Spikes on different time intervals high load of PHP-FPM processes even during non-peak hours. I want to ensure that the configuration is optimized for both performance and resource efficiency.
TOP Command at time of issue:

top - 11:48:34 up 874 days, 21:08, 1 user, load average: 49.72, 49.53, 42.80
Tasks: 214 total, 50 running, 110 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 96.8%us, 2.9%sy, 0.1%ni, 0.0%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.2%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 15951580k total, 15737856k used, 213724k free, 142396k buffers
Swap: 0k total, 0k used, 0k free, 9243988k cached

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
30056 apache 20 0 769m 215m 159m R 18.3 1.4 4:34.05 php-fpm
30050 apache 20 0 781m 262m 193m R 18.0 1.7 4:32.23 php-fpm
30060 apache 20 0 786m 240m 166m R 17.3 1.5 4:32.23 php-fpm
30064 apache 20 0 784m 248m 178m R 17.3 1.6 4:31.67 php-fpm
29242 apache 20 0 806m 271m 177m R 17.0 1.7 5:22.64 php-fpm
29243 apache 20 0 787m 276m 203m R 17.0 1.8 5:32.13 php-fpm
29388 apache 20 0 789m 280m 204m R 17.0 1.8 5:11.79 php-fpm
29389 apache 20 0 771m 282m 226m R 17.0 1.8 5:14.63 php-fpm
30067 apache 20 0 777m 242m 176m R 17.0 1.6 4:33.43 php-fpm
29380 apache 20 0 771m 242m 184m R 16.6 1.6 5:18.49 php-fpm
29391 apache 20 0 785m 241m 174m R 16.6 1.6 5:16.27 php-fpm
30055 apache 20 0 767m 200m 147m R 16.6 1.3 4:32.00 php-fpm
29236 apache 20 0 778m 240m 176m R 16.3 1.5 5:32.46 php-fpm
7329 apache 20 0 807m 338m 245m R 16.0 2.2 15:59.15 php-fpm
29239 apache 20 0 782m 255m 186m R 16.0 1.6 5:46.10 php-fpm
29245 apache 20 0 785m 273m 201m R 16.0 1.8 5:20.65 php-fpm
29392 apache 20 0 785m 274m 201m R 16.0 1.8 5:02.05 php-fpm
30054 apache 20 0 771m 239m 180m R 16.0 1.5 4:35.17 php-fpm
29233 apache 20 0 782m 240m 170m R 15.6 1.5 5:33.47 php-fpm
29234 apache 20 0 796m 276m 192m R 15.6 1.8 5:33.33 php-fpm
29235 apache 20 0 792m 303m 224m R 15.6 1.9 5:16.15 php-fpm
29237 apache 20 0 821m 295m 186m R 15.6 1.9 5:34.35 php-fpm
29238 apache 20 0 768m 227m 175m S 15.6 1.5 5:22.32 php-fpm
29384 apache 20 0 788m 265m 189m R 15.6 1.7 5:33.77 php-fpm
29387 apache 20 0 805m 285m 195m R 15.6 1.8 5:14.28 php-fpm
30048 apache 20 0 770m 285m 227m R 15.6 1.8 4:33.40 php-fpm
30053 apache 20 0 774m 247m 184m R 15.6 1.6 4:32.99 php-fpm
30061 apache 20 0 788m 280m 206m R 15.6 1.8 4:31.77 php-fpm
30063 apache 20 0 787m 259m 186m R 15.6 1.7 4:34.28 php-fpm
7328 apache 20 0 797m 307m 230m R 15.3 2.0 16:44.80 php-fpm
7330 apache 20 0 822m 354m 247m R 15.3 2.3 15:21.52 php-fpm
7332 apache 20 0 806m 323m 228m R 15.3 2.1 17:10.16 php-fpm
29231 apache 20 0 790m 291m 217m R 15.3 1.9 5:20.02 php-fpm
29241 apache 20 0 777m 271m 206m R 15.3 1.7 5:30.39 php-fpm
29244 apache 20 0 796m 285m 203m R 15.3 1.8 5:32.68 php-fpm

CPU Graph at time of Issue:
Cpu.png

Note:DB CPU was in normal range through out the time

If you've encountered a similar situation or have expertise in tuning PHP-FPM for Magento, I would greatly appreciate any advice, best practices, or recommendations you could share. Additionally, if there are specific metrics or tools you recommend for monitoring and adjusting PHP-FPM settings in a Magento environment, please feel free to suggest them.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance. I look forward to hearing from the Magento community experts!

Comment: Let's find out how many Sleeping processes your server is managing with this query. 

    SELECT 'SLEEPING Ram use', 
       COUNT(*),SUM(time),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) 
         FROM information_schema.processlist 
    WHERE 
    command="Sleep";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat, you set maximum children **too high** for an 8-core machine.

A rule of thumb I'm using - `max_children = # of CPU cores.`

Static distribution performs better from my experience.

Try different solutions:

- Switch to `pm = static` with `pm.max_children = 8`
- You might have a code bottleneck. Hook up the site to a code profiler (new relic, tideways or similar, just google for them, they are all good). It will show you what slows the site down
- Do a 3rd-party extension audit. My experience tells me it's a custom extension that breaks performance. Turn them all off and see if it makes a difference. Kind of hard to do on a live site but if you could.

What you need to do is to try and optimize TTFB (time to first byte), then you wouldn't need so many php-fpm processes.

And in the end, of course, it could be as simple as:

```
php bin/magento cache:enable
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your exp i will config it according to VM.